# Does anyone have a script that lets you log in to chat server side?

Tags: discussion, chat

There doesn't seem to be any sort of API for chat. I'm working on creating one, however I'm stuck at the login bit.

How can I get Python (or some other server side language) to log in to chat? The process of chat login is a bit convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a litany of Github attempts, from new to old:

- [cabbage.js](https://github.com/poke/CabbageBot.js/blob/master/lib/cabbage.js)
- [rebolbot.r3](https://github.com/gchiu/rebolbot/blob/master/rebolbot.r3)
- [soirc.py](https://github.com/ghewgill/soirc/blob/master/soirc.py)
- [soxmpp.rb](https://github.com/hmblprogrammer/SOXMPP/blob/master/soxmpp.rb)
- [stackChat.py](https://github.com/aking1012/stackChat)

Comment: The first two don't really satisfy the criteria in the question, both are not purely headless (the second requires some Wiresharking)

Comment: Never got around to figuring out how the login works ... but will need to look at it soon as rebolbot can get disconnected after a month or so, and we need to provide new credentials.